# Error de sintaxis en mysql

Tags: mysql, sintaxis

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo de mysql pero no se me ejecuta correctamente a la hora de crear la ultima tabla de todas la de actores si alguien sabe porque le agradeceria si me lo puede decir

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS FILMOTECA;
CREATE DATABASE FILMOTECA;
USE FILMOTECA;
CREATE TABLE GENEROS (
    codigo VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(40)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES (
    nombre VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(20),
    fechaNacimiento DATE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE  ACTORESPELICULAS (
    pelicula VARCHAR(30),
    actor VARCHAR(20),
    personaje VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (pelicula, actor)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE PELICULAS (
    codigo VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    genero VARCHAR(10),
    titulo VARCHAR(30),
    director VARCHAR(25),
    anio INT,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_ACTORESPELICULAS_pelicula`
     FOREIGN KEY (codigo) REFERENCES ACTORESPELICULAS (pelicula)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_GENEROS_codigo`
     FOREIGN KEY (genero) REFERENCES GENEROS (codigo)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_DIRECTORES_nombre`
     FOREIGN KEY (director) REFERENCES DIRECTORES (nombre)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE ACTORES (
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(30),
    fechaNacim DATE,
    sexo VARCHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_ACTORESPELICULAS_actor`
     FOREIGN KEY (nombre) REFERENCES ACTORESPELICULAS (actor)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=Innodb;

SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW TABLES;

SHOW CREATE TABLE ACTORES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE PELICULAS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE ACTORESPELICULAS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE GENEROS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES;
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 40 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/MartinSosa_Antonio_filmoteca.sql': Can't create table `FILMOTECA`.`ACTORES` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

La linea/tabla a la que hace referencia el error es esta:

```
 CREATE TABLE ACTORES (
        nombre VARCHAR(20),
        nacionalidad VARCHAR(30),
        fechaNacim DATE,
        sexo VARCHAR(1),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_ACTORESPELICULAS_actor`
         FOREIGN KEY (nombre) REFERENCES ACTORESPELICULAS (actor)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=Innodb;
```

Realmente no se porque me dice que esta mal definida la clave foranea si que yo sepa esta igual que las otras tablas y las otras se crean sin problema alguno
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: no deberia ser al reves la key??? nombre de actor es foreign key de actores... igual, nunca uses los nombres como PK!!!! que pasa si lo escribiste mal? no lo vas apoder cambiar... se usan id autonumericos como pk...

Comment: Ya lo se pero es un ejercicio de clase por eso que use eso como clave primaria debido al ejercicio igualmente a q te refieres exactamente con al reves la key?

Comment: primero deberias cargar el actor, y luego agregarlo a actores peliculas... no? si no, que sentido tiene la tabla actores...

Comment: Hola ya he conseguido resolverlo muchas gracias mira mi respuesta a ver que te parece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de @gbianchi e conseguido llegar a la solución
El problema era que no estaba declarando bien las claves foraneas, despues de volver a hacer las relaccion como ya me habia comentando @gbianchi la clave foranea tendria que ir de la tabla ACTORES a la tabla ACTORESPELICULAS y no de ACTORESPELICULAS a ACTORES como yo estaba indicando.
Dejo como quedo el codigo al final despues de arreglar las relacciones y tener claras las claves foraneas:

```
#Antonio Martin Sosa 12/12/2022

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS FILMOTECA;
CREATE DATABASE FILMOTECA;
USE FILMOTECA;
CREATE TABLE GENEROS (
    codigo VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(40)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES (
    nombre VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(20),
    fechaNacimiento DATE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE  ACTORESPELICULAS (
    pelicula VARCHAR(10),
    actor VARCHAR(20),
    personaje VARCHAR(40),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_ACTORES_nombre`
     FOREIGN KEY (actor) REFERENCES ACTOR (nombre)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_PELICULAS_codigo`
     FOREIGN KEY (pelicula) REFERENCES PELICULAS (codigo)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE PELICULAS (
    codigo VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    genero VARCHAR(10),
    titulo VARCHAR(30),
    director VARCHAR(25),
    anio INT,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_GENEROS_codigo`
     FOREIGN KEY (genero) REFERENCES GENEROS (codigo)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_DIRECTORES_nombre`
     FOREIGN KEY (director) REFERENCES DIRECTORES (nombre)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE ACTORES (
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    nacionalidad VARCHAR(30),
    fechaNacim DATE,
    sexo VARCHAR(1)
) ENGINE=Innodb;

SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW TABLES;

SHOW CREATE TABLE ACTORES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE PELICULAS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE ACTORESPELICULAS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE GENEROS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE DIRECTORES;
```

Se puede observar el cambio de claves foraneas aqui:

```
CREATE TABLE  ACTORESPELICULAS (
    pelicula VARCHAR(10),
    actor VARCHAR(20),
    personaje VARCHAR(40),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_ACTORES_nombre`
     FOREIGN KEY (actor) REFERENCES ACTOR (nombre)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_PELICULAS_codigo`
     FOREIGN KEY (pelicula) REFERENCES PELICULAS (codigo)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

Como se ve se han cambiado las claves foraneas que iban desde ACTORESPELICULAS a PELICULAS/ACTORES y ahora van al contrario de PELICULAS/ACTORES a ACTORESPELICULAS
Muchas gracias espero que a alguien ademas de a mi le sea de ayuda